# Possible async problem with firebase get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function `useVenue` that returns venue data from a call to firebase:

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import { firebase } from './firebaseConfig'

export  function useVenues (){
  const [venues, setVenues] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const venueArray = [];
    const getAllVenues = async () => {
      await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("venues")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((venue) => {
            venueArray.push(venue);
          });
          setVenues(venueArray);
        });
    };
    getAllVenues();
  }, []);

  const [...venueData] = venues.map((venue) => {
    
    const { 
      name, 
      photoUrl, 
      averageRating, 
      numRatings, 
      type,
      address,
      phone,
      website,
      reviews } = venue.data();

    return ({
      name: name,
      photoUrl: photoUrl,
      averageRating: averageRating,
      numRatings: numRatings,
      type: type,
      id: venue.id,
      reviews:reviews,
      address:address,
      phone:phone,
      website:website
    })
  });
  return {venueData}
};
```

This function is exported to `venues.js` where the venue data is destructured out and pass as props to `MidSection.js`:

***venues.js***

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useVenues } from '../useVenue';
import Header from '../components/Header'
import VenueDetails from '../components/venue-page/VenueDetails'
import MidSection from '../components/venue-page/MidSection';
import ReviewSection from '../components/venue-page/ReviewSection';

const Venue = () => {

    let {id} = useParams()
    const { venueData } = useVenues()

    const filteredVenue = venueData.filter(item => {
        return item.id === id
    })

    return(
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <VenueDetails filteredVenue = {filteredVenue}/>
            <MidSection filteredVenue = {filteredVenue}/>
            <ReviewSection filteredVenue = {filteredVenue} id = {id}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Venue
```

Lastly, in mid section I want to pull some information out of the venue data, passed as props as `filteredvenue`. I'm extracting this data with the following function:

```
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import { convertToStars } from "../../helperFunctions";

const MidSection = ({ filteredVenue }) => {


  const extractRatings =   () => {
    const foodRatings = []
    filteredVenue[0].reviews.map((rating) => {
     foodRatings.push(rating.ratingFood)
    })
    return {foodRatings}
  }

  const {foodRatings} = extractRatings()
```

I logged out `foodRatings` and it returned the data I wanted. However when I refreshed the browser, the app crashed, giving the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reviews')

I'm assuming this is some sort of asynchronous error and that the browser is rendering this component before the data has been returned. Unsure why this is happening since I'm using `async/await` in the initial firebase `useVenues` function, and the `filteredVenue` object is being mapped through elsewhere in this component with no problems. Suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Josh Simon, According to the error the ```reviews``` variable is undefined. So, to debug further, I suggest you put ```log``` statements to display ```filteredVenue``` , ```venueData``` and also after retrieving the data from Firestore. I also suggest you to provide the Firestore database structure.

Answer (score 0):

`import { firebase } from './firebaseConfig'`

problem is with firebase config you are using, when it resolve but have error